RuntimeError: Unknown impersonate version: edge_99 when using DDGS with DuckDuckGo Search
I'm trying to use the duckduckgo_search Python package to search for specific texts+keyword and retrieve the first link.
However, I'm encountering an error related to the impersonate version when calling the DDGS class after retrieving few links.
The Error
RuntimeError: Unknown impersonate version: edge_99
The search function should return the link to the first result on the page as in the function bellow.
from duckduckgo_search import DDGS
import re

def get_agent_link(query):
    with DDGS() as ddgs: #This is where I get the error
        results = ddgs.text(query, max_results=30)
        
        for result in results:
            url = result['href']
            if 'website.com/agent' in url:
                match = re.search(r'some regex', url)  
                if match:
                    agent_identifier = match.group(1)
                    return f"https://website.com/agent/{agent_identifier}" 
    
    return None

I am running the code from google Calab
I have tried updating the package to the latest version.
How can I fix this issue, or is there a workaround to avoid this error?

I'm stuck with what seems the same problem. I think the problem is in the last release. Downgrading to an older version solved it for me:
pip install duckduckgo-search==6.2.2

I'm using Arch Linux btw, so this may not work on MS Windows machines.
